# Is it possible to suppress commit message editing

Tags: git, git-commit

Often times, I make edits on top of an existing commit, then run

```
git commit -a --amend
```

It then asks to edit the existing commit message, which I don't need to change. Is there a way to amend without editing the message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `--no-edit` to just keep the original commit message

```
git commit --amend --no-edit
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me. However `git commit -a --amend --no-edit` seems to work.